# How to transfer Twilio lookup cURL code to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, twilio, twilio-php

I have this curl code:

```
curl -X GET https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/(919) 410-7522\
-d "Type=carrier"
-u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}"
```

I try to convert in PHP cURL but I stack on how to send `AccountSid` and `AuthToken`.

I need this code only to [check if number is valid and mobile or landline](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups#lookups-carrier-info).

How to do that? Thanks!

Comment: A dump from wireshark would be nice of possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option

```
$ch = curl_init("https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/(919)%20410-7522");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Type=carrier");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: This is great only for some reason return me message that AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect what is not true. I have verified account.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić Contact Twilio's support, then.

Comment: Thanks I will figureout that but this code is perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

echo time()."<br/>";


$cmd="curl -XGET 'https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/+19999999999?Type=carrier&Type=caller-name' -u 'YOURUSERACCOUNT:YOURAUTHTOKEN' ";
$result=shell_exec($cmd);



$response           =       json_decode($result);
echo "country_code is ".$response->country_code."<br/>";    
echo "<pre>";   print_r($response); echo "</pre><br/>";

echo "country_code is ".$response->country_code."<br/><br/>";

echo "phone number is ".$response->phone_number."<br/>";
echo "national_format ".$response->national_format."<br/><br/>";


$carrier=json_decode($response->carrier);   

echo "Carrier name is ".$response->carrier->name."<br/>";
echo "Carrier type is ".$response->carrier->type."<br/>";
echo "Carrier error_code is ".$response->carrier->error_code."<br/>";
echo "Carrier mobile_network_code ".$response->carrier->mobile_network_code."<br/>";
echo "Carrier mobile_country_code is ".$response->carrier->mobile_country_code."<br/><br/>";

$caller_name=json_decode($response->caller_name);
echo "caller_name is ".$response->caller_name->caller_name."<br/>";
echo "caller_name error_code is ".$response->caller_name->error_code."<br/>";






?>

    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt getting the carrier response so i changed to shell_exec using the curl xget command listed on twilio and it worked fine

Comment: This is not helpfull. Can you explain?

Comment: i added an answer sample